# unpack syntax in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, unpack

I am trying to convert hex numbers into decimals using unpack.
When I use:

```
from struct import *
unpack("<H",b"\xe2\x07")
```

The output is: `2018`, which is what I want.
The thing is I have my hex data in a list as a string in the form of:

```
asd = ['e2','07']
```

My question is is there a simple way of using unpack without the backslashes, the x? Something like so:

```
unpack("<H","e207")
```

I know this doesn't work but I hope you get the idea.

For clarification I know I could get the data in the form of `b'\x11'` in the list but then it's interpreted as ASCII, which I don't want, that's why I have it in the format I showed.

Answer (score 2):

You have hex-encoded data, in a text object.  So, to go back to raw hex bytes, you can *decode* the text string.  Please note that this is not the usual convention in Python 3.x (generally, text strings are already decoded).

```
>>> codecs.decode('e207', 'hex')
b'\xe2\x07'
```

A convenience function for the same thing:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('e207')
b'\xe2\x07'
```

Now you can `struct.unpack` those bytes.  Putting it all together:

```
>>> asd = ['e2','07']
>>> text = ''.join(asd)
>>> encoded = codecs.decode(text, 'hex')
>>> struct.unpack("<H", encoded)
(2018,)
```

Comment: will there be any ascii interpretation using codecs.decode()? because in my case i have a huge list containing of hundreds of hex strings and i don´t want them to be interpreted at any point

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ascii interpretation". Ideally, you should locate the code that mistakenly saves binary data as text data, and change that code to just save binary data in the first place.

Comment: what i mean is that if i use print() to show the hexa numbers, python shows them allready interpreted in ascii

Comment: As long as they are all 0-9 a-f then it doesn't matter.